# Session not created null reference exception in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I doing with sessions. On first page I have code

```
Response.Redirect("welcome.aspx");
Session["me"] = TextBox1.Text;
```

and on welcome page I am writing this code on form load event

```
if(Session["me"] != null)
{
  Label1.Text = (string)Session["me"];
}
else
{
  Label1.Text = "session not created";
}
```

it gives me "Session not created" else part is running always. Is something wrong with my code. please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create the session before redirect to the page so your code must be
like this:

```
Session["me"] = TextBox1.Text;
    Response.Redirect("welcome.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `session` before `redirecting` to other page

```
Session["me"] = TextBox1.Text;
Response.Redirect("welcome.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Session["me"] = TextBox1.Text;
```

and use it before redirecting to other page

Answer (score 1):

You have to first set the session and then redirect to other page. so it should be like this:

```
Session["me"] = TextBox1.Text; // set the session
Response.Redirect("welcome.aspx"); // redirect to other page
```